# Nagios : Setting alerts based in value returned

Tags: mysql, nagios

I am using the plugin check_mysql_health with great success for monitoring MySQL Server. Now, I have encountered a new customization which involves setting the alerts as per the thresholds.

For eg : If I write the following sql mode in check_mysql_health,

```
select count(*) from revenue where amount > 100000
```

I get the result as 10.

Suppose, I want to give an alert based on the value received, such as CRITICAL when result < 10, how am I supposed to configure that ?

Any help regarding this will be amazing. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **--critical** and **--warning**

`check_mysql_health --mode sql --name select... --critical 10:`

And use colon after value for <, without colon for >

- 10: => alert if < 10
- 90 => alert if > 90

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Only one question more, can the result be a variable ? Like at 10:00 AM it should be checked for 10, at 3:00 PM for 20 and at 6:00 PM for 30. Something like this.

Comment: You could create a script that calculates what critical/warning value would be (criticalValue = 10, if ( time ... ) criticalValue = 20), after that just call check_mysql... --critical criticalValue and exit with the status of that command (exit $?, because nagios checks plugins exit status to know if it's critical, ok, ... 0 = ok, 1 = warning, 2 = critical, 3 = unknown) Then in nagios command configuration call your new script instead of check_mysql